# Jquery find element with style attr and change it

Tags: jquery, attr

I have:

```
<div style="color:red">
  some text
</div>
<div style="color:green; height:100px;">
  some more text
</div>
```

And I want to select div with `style color:green;height:100px;` and change it to lets say `color:blue; height:10px;`

I've tried:

```
$("div").each(function(){
       if($(this).css("height")=="100px"){
          $(this).css("color","blue");
       }
    });
```

and

```
$("div").find(attr('style','color:green'))...
```

but with no luck

Comment: What you said you tried works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c3kL3pd6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use wild cards:

```
$("div[style*=green][style*=100px]")...
```

Just make sure you don't accidentally get other elements.

Comment: Strange. It works great in Jsfiddle but not in my project :(